# Why can't "Type" be a column name in SharePoint list?

Tags: list, excel

I am new to SharePoint list and PowerApps. When I create lists, I can not add a column name called "Type". It said the column name already exists but the column was not in my list. When I import a table from an excel sheet, which contains a column name called "Type" then it won't import. Is type a reserved word in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fields / columns name are reserved in SharePoint list and library. these names can not be use to create custom columns in list.

I would recommend use different name containing some noun. e.g. Employee Type, Risk Type .

Below are the list reserved column with their internal name in SharePoint list.

| TITLE | INTERNAL NAME |
| --- | --- |
| Created | Created |
| Created | Created_x0020_Date |
| Created By | Author |
| Edit | Edit |
| File Type | File_x0020_Type |
| GUID | GUID |
| ID | ID |
| Modified | Modified |
| Modified | Last_x0020_Modified |
| Modified By | Editor |
| Name | FileLeafRef |
| Name | LinkFilenameNoMenu |
| Name | LinkFilename |
| Name | BaseName |
| Title | Title |
| Type | DocIcon |

Answer (score 0):

Because **Type** is reserved column name in SharePoint so you can't use it